# Condition table theory

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, best-practices, database-theory, condition

Is there a good way to create a "table of conditions"?

I have a huge table, where 4-5 columns are considered in a set of rules, and based on those columns default values must appear in other columns. The update part, I can do.

I would like for the whole thing to be user maintainable: they should be able to open a table and change, delete or add rules. They can do it with a table, but they can't edit a code.

A simplified version would be something like this:

If ColumnA = 1 AND ColumnB = 2 THEN X
If ColumnA = 1 AND ColumnB IS empty (NULL) THEN Y
If Column A = 3 AND ColumnB IS anything THEN Z

Is there a nice way to do this? I can programmatically loop through the rows and construct update queries, but it will be desperately slow, and will run as many updates as many condition rows there are. Seems wasteful.

I came up with a token for "anything": (*), and I can use this in a horrid SQL, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

```
SELECT M.*
FROM MainData M
INNER JOIN Rules R
ON ((M.Check2 = R.C2) OR R.C2="(*)" OR (R.C2 IS NULL AND M.Check2 IS NULL))
  AND ((M.Check1 = R.C1) OR R.C1="(*)" OR (R.C1 IS NULL AND M.Check1 IS NULL))
```

To make matters worse this is MS Access, but I'm actually interested in the concept at this point.

Comment: I am not sure what you are going for with the rules table here. For the example with the IF's you could go for CASE WHEN statements. (`CASE WHEN  ColumnA = 1 AND ColumnB = 2 THEN X WHEN ColumnA = 1 AND ColumnB IS empty (NULL) THEN Y WHEN  Column A = 3 THEN Z END AS Column`. I would really try to refrain from using `OR`'s and `AND`'s like the last example, for performance reasons.

Comment: @RandiVertongen The point is I don't want to hardcode the 80+ rules for the 80+ different outcomes. Not just out of lazyness, I want it to be user editable. I can tell the users they need to add a new row in such and such table if they want a new rule. I should add this to the question...

Comment: We would really need a real world / working example. If a user adds a rule, you would have to change the query anyways right? Could you add an example with these rules and adding a rule? It looks like you want to add columns to both tables when a rule is added

Comment: You could parse records from the table and use dynamic SQL to formulate your final query, but as [my post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/242770/39083) on [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/242755/39083) states, it's best to avoid Dynamic SQL in production code as you ***WILL RUN INTO ISSUES***.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener Thank you. I too am wary of dynamic SQL. I'll try to come up with a table that I can just join.